# How to allow wordpress users to upload directly to youtube or vimeo?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, upload, youtube, vimeo

Is anyone aware of a way to allow users through wordpress to upload video straight to my youtube or vimeo account? My original plan was to allow the users to upload directly to my dropbox account which I had linked to my Vimeo account but unfortunately the functionality that Vimeo promises is less than reliable, https://vimeo.com/help/faq/uploading-to-vimeo/uploading-from-dropbox. I also found a version using the old API for youtube, https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading#Uploading_the_Video_File but it doesn't seem like anyone has had any luck on the new API. Any comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a WordPress plugin available that allows you to upload directly to your Vimeo account.

http://vimeography.com/add-ons/vimeography-upload/

Source: I made it :)

Comment: Will this allow visitors to upload content from the frontend without having to sign in?

Comment: No, but I did write another plugin that extends from Ninja Forms to provide that capability. Reach out with the support form on the link I provided above and I'll give you more info.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I just sent you an email to the contact form. This would be an awesome help. I would imagine vimeo pro is needed correct?